# Convert an xarray variable to a dask array for svd computation

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray, chunks, svd

I have a chunked dataset that has a tall and skinny variable.
I'd like to calculate its SVD but as far as I know, xarray does not do that on chunks. Chunks are important otherwise the SVD calculation overloads my RAM.

Is there a way to convert dataset's variable (chunked) to a `dask.array.Array` in order to apply `dask.array.linalg.svd()` ?

If I input my dataset `ds` in the dask svd function, I get the error:
`AttributeError: 'DataArray' object has no attribute 'numblocks'`

Example code to generate dataset:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da

time = np.arange(200)
space = np.arange(700000)

data = np.random.rand(200, 700000)  # Generating random data

# Create the xarray dataset
ds = xr.Dataset(
    {"variable": (("time", "space"), data)},
    coords={"time": time, "space": space},
).chunk({'time':-1, 'space':100000})
```